# Program which displays the all signed short numbers

Tags: c, ansi-c

*EDIT: I Deleted by mistake the remarks I wrote on that using short & char is kind of obsolete / not efficient in modern programming. this one is just for practice basic stuff.**

This program creates and prints the series of signed short values starting from their equivalent in the unsigned short "space/world" starting at value 0 .

**example : on a machine where short is 16 bit :
         unsigned short : 0 1 2 .... 65535
       => signed short :  0 1 2 ... 32766 -32767 -32766 -32765 ... -2 -1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

//Initialize memory pointed by p with values 0 1 ... n
//Assumption : the value of n can be converted to 
//             short int (without over/under-flow)
unsigned int initArr (short int *p, unsigned int n);

int main (void)
{
  const unsigned int lastNumInSeq = USHRT_MAX;
  short *p_arr = (short *) malloc ( (lastNumInSeq + 1) * sizeof (short));
  short int lastValSet = initArr (p_arr, lastNumInSeq); //returns the "max" val written

//  for (unsigned i = 0; i < numOfElem; i++)
//      printf ("[%d]=%d \n", i, (*(p_arr + i)));

  printf ("lastValSet = %d *(p_arr + lastNumInSeq) = %d  ",
           lastValSet,*(p_arr + lastNumInSeq ));

  return 0;
}

unsigned int initArr (short *p, unsigned int n)
{
  unsigned int offset,index = 0;

  while (index <= n){
      offset = index;
      *(p + offset) = ++index -1 ;
  }

  return offset;
```

Comment: `*(p + index) = ( -1 + (++index) ); //is this robust?` : This is UB.

Comment: "Undefined Behavior"... something to read up on...

Comment: UB is undefined behavior.

Comment: Because the timing of side effects of `++index` is not deterministic, the result of this expression is not uniquely determined.

Comment: So Different compilers may get different results.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , Can you please elaborate? I've just read few days ago about that i++ is divided into 2 steps (saving the old value, and increment) , and that ++i is more effictient (though most modern compilers know how to optimize i++  easy) . but I guess thats not what you are talking about... are you talking about Atomic operations? (context switch etc.)

Comment: See [c11 draft 6.5 Expressions p2 and  footnote (84)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: In case of `*p  =  -1 + (++index);` is well defined.

Comment: If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
effect occurs in any of the orderings.84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
i = ++i + 1;
a[i++] = i;
while allowing
i = i + 1;
a[i] = i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other cleanups needed.

The function signature should change from

```
    short initArr (short *p, unsigned int n);
```

to

```
    unsigned int initArr (short *p, unsigned int n);
```

The variable 'lastValSet' should change its type to unsigned int.

This comment is also confusing:

```
    //Assumption : the value of n can be converted to 
    //             short int (without over/under-flow)
```

It should be something like:

```
    //Assumption : the value of n which is of type int can be converted to 
    //             short int (without over/under-flow) up to 32767 which is the 
    //             max value for a variable of short type.
```